# Evaluate this integral of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Evaluate the integral
> $$\int \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots\right)\:\:dx$$
> This problem was apparently given in a competitive exam but was declared wrong for some anonymous reasons.

My initial thoughts:

I think that we have to form the concise form of the given expression. This isn't a normal progression. I tried clubbing odd powers together and then the same with even powers. I can't conclude it's concise form. According to me, we can re-write this as,
$$\int\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i}\cdot(-1)^{i+1}\:\:dx$$ I can't find the value of the summation. Also, I don't see any common or similar thing in this expression $$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^5}{20}+\cdots$$
This is the evaluation of the integral by calculating each term separately.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key fact I imagine is to use the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$:

$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} x^k$$

The resulting integral can be integrated via integration by parts, though I'm not sure why off-hand this might be considered off-limits for a competition (especially because it's not a particularly difficult one). Maybe they listed only the wrong answer or something?

Comment: If $|x|>1$ or $x=-1$, the integrand doesn't converge. I wonder if that was the issue.

Comment: @PrincessEev yes...they have listed wrong answers

Comment: @PrincessEev so, we will just have to evaluate $$\int \ln(x+1)\:\:dx$$ $?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series evaluates to $\ln(x+1)$ for $|x|<1$. Just recall that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2}+...$, integrate both sides and take $x$ to be $-x$.

So now the issue is with evaluating $\int \ln (x+1)dx$.

$$ \int \ln (x+1)dx = x\ln(x+1) - \int \frac{x}{x+1}dx = (x+1)\ln(x+1) - (x+1) + C. $$

If $|x| > 1$, the integral diverges because the sum diverges. For $x=1$ it does not make sense to integrate since the sum does not make sense in the neighbourhood of $x=1$, it only makes sense in the left neighbourhood of it.

Comment: what if $|x|\ge1?$

Comment: If $|x| > 1$, the integral diverges. For $x=1$ it does not make sense to integrate since the sum does not make sense in the neighbourhood of $x=1$.

Comment: It only makes sense it the left neighbourhood of $x=1$ but that is not enough.